# Parsing JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm getting an error while parsing a JSON response in Python. Ex:

```
{
    "oneliners": [
        "she\'s the one",
        "who opened the gates"
    ]
}
```

The JSON decoder coughs up on the invalid escape on the single quote. Typically do people apply a REGEX to remove the escape slash character prior to decoding a response that can potentially contain an invalid escape?

Comment: What JSON decoder are you using?

Comment: @sdolan: Any *strict* JSON decoder (simplejson for instance - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) will choke on that, it really is an invalid escape in JSON (as opposed to JavaScript): http://json.org

Answer (score 1):

Pyparsing ships with a JSON parsing example (or you can get it online [here](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/jsonParser.py)):

```
>>> text = r"""{
...     "oneliners": [
...         "she\'s the one",
...         "who opened the gates"
...     ]
... } """
>>> text
'{       \n    "oneliners": [       \n        "she\\\'s the one",       \n        "who opened the gates"       \n    ]       \n} '
>>> obj = jsonObject.parseString(text)
>>> obj.asList()
[['oneliners', ["she\\'s the one", 'who opened the gates']]]
>>> obj.asDict()
{'oneliners': (["she\\'s the one", 'who opened the gates'], {})}
>>> obj.oneliners
(["she\\'s the one", 'who opened the gates'], {})
>>> obj.oneliners.asList()
["she\\'s the one", 'who opened the gates']
```

Don't be put off by the seeming inclusion of a dict (the '{}') in `obj.oneliners`, that is just the repr output for a pyparsing ParseResults object.  You can just treat obj.oneliners like an ordinary list - or if you like, extract its contents as a list using `asList` as shown.

Answer (score 1):

if you have `\'` character sequence in your JSON string representation, and you KNOW it should be `'`, it means it was improperly escaped before, you should fix the problem there.

if you can't, you should do the replacement before you provide such a string to the JSON parser. `simplejson` will fail parsing it, `cjson` or `anyjson` would not fail, but will handle it literally, so you will have the backslash-apostrophe sequence in the resulting data.

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
s = """{
 "oneliners": [
 "she\'s the one",
 "who opened the gates"
 ]
}"""

print "%r" % json.loads(s)
```

This appears to work just fine, in Python 2.6 and upwards anyway.

Comment: Must define s using a raw string, or json.loads will never see that '\'. (And I'm not the one who downvoted you.)

Comment: Could have sworn that I tried the raw version of the string, I'm sorry, what a terrible first post.